# Python: append split list is empty

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

My objective or output I'm looking for is to append to input txt file the first part of all lines of existing input file. As an example:

```
Input:
line_item1 string1
line_item2 string2
line_item3 string3

Output:
line_item1 string1
line_item2 string2
line_item3 string3
line_item1   # append
line_item2   # append
line_item3   # append
```

The code I have created does not output anything:

```
portionA = []
with open('output outfile.txt', "a+") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        parts = line.strip().split("\t", 1)
        portionA = parts[0]
        portionB = parts[1]
        portionA.append(line)
        f.write('{}\n'.format(''.join(portionA)))
```

Comment: This is fairly unclear. Can you provide some actual examples? What do you mean by 'selected lines'?

Comment: I see you want to append the same lines at end. Deleted my answer

Comment: @user1739581 On second thought, it does look my instincts were right. Have undeleted and updated my answer. Please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
with open('output outfile.txt', "a+") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        parts = line.strip().split("\t")
        f.write('{}\n'.format(parts[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'r+' instead of 'a+'.

```
``r+''  Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned at the
         beginning of the file.
```

Why a+ doesn't work is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14639957/2599266)

I can't correct the indents on your code for the f.write so here's the corrected snippet (Note the join with \n instead of empty string)

```
writeList= []
with open('outfile.txt', "r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.strip().split("\t", 1)
        portionA = parts[0]
        portionB = parts[1]
        writeList.append(line)
    f.write('{}\n'.format('\n'.join(writeList)))
```

Comment: This would be better as a comment.